# how to set state_pressed color of a listView programmatically

Tags: android, listview

I am (trying to do) writing a program without xml files (the android documentation says that it is possible) but I have a lot difficulties to find informations for some details.

I would like to replace the ugly orange color when an item is being touched by an neutral color. ***Dose somebody know how we can do it inside the program? for a ListView which has not a R.loayout representation?***

Thanks in advance for answers...

some talks about this:

> ```
>   ColorStateList c = new ColorStateList( 
>              new int[][] {
>                      new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed},
>                      new int[1]
>                  }, new int[] {
>                      Color.rgb(50, 50, 255),
>                      Color.BLACK,
>                  });
> ```

But how to set it to my list view?

the creation of the list view is the following:

```
private class mybaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (portList == null)
            return 0;
        return portList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Log.v("getItem", portList.get(position).toString());
        return portList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("getView", portList.get(position).toString());
        return portList.get(position);
    }
}

    ListView lv = new ListView(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lv.setAdapter(new mybaseAdapter());
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.v("onItemClick", "Clicked item is");
        }
    });
    addView(lv, lp);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) After you've created it you can set it to the background of your View with `v.setBackgroundDrawable(yourStateListDrawable);`

Comment: Thank you very mutch, it was the right way; 'I did add   int[] a = new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed };
  st.addState(a, new ColorDrawable(0xFF0000FF));
  setBackgroundDrawable(st);' on the item on list, I can not vote for you, I have not yet 15 reputations,  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Set Listview Property Runtime like this

list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);